# Custom datatype for PyTorch geometric layers?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am trying to build a GNN using the PyTorch geometric library (https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I am building a simple network as follows:

```
class GNetComplex(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(input_size, hidden_size, dtype = torch.cfloat)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size, dtype = torch.cfloat)

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
        
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.tanh(x)
        
        x = global_mean_pool(x, data.batch)
        x = self.output_layer(x)

        x = torch.abs(x)

        return x
```

However, the GCN is not actually getting initialized with complex valued weights, and I get an error:

```
  return F.linear(x, self.weight, self.bias)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: expected scalar type ComplexFloat but found Float
```

How would I go about initializing the layer with a custom type?